# How do we calculate the characters of a linear algebraic group?

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

A character $\chi:G \to \mathbb{G}_m$ is a map from an algebraic group $G$ into the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m.$ How do we calculate explicitly the characters of a certain group?

I know the following example: Consider a torus $T=\{diag(a_1,a_2,a_3)\},$ where $diag(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is a matrix with $a_1,a_2,a_3$ on the main diagonal and zeros elsewhere. The characters of $T$ are the maps $\chi_i:diag(a_1,a_2,a_3) \to a_i.$

More specifically, what are the characters of $SL_n?$ or the unipotent subgroup of $GL_n?$

Comment: $T$ has countably many characters; they're maps of the form $a_1^{m_1} a_2^{m_2} a_3^{m_3}$ where $m_1 ,m_2, m_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I meant to say it is the group generated by $\chi_1, \chi_2$ and $\chi_3.$

Comment: You should specify how $G$ is given (algorithmically) and what you mean by _"calculate explicitly"_.

Comment: A character of a group will be an invertible element in the coordinate ring of the group. You can use this to see that the unipotent group of upper triangular matrices with $1$'s along the diagonal has trivial character group: its coordinate ring is a polynomial ring, so only the scalars are invertible.